# Logical expression, simplifying

Tags: expression, simplify, demorgans-law

I am currently trying to learn how to simplify logical expressions.
But I got stuck on this one task were I am to prove that the expression is either a tautology or a contradiction.
I would like some help with simplifying the following expression:

(a and not b) or (not a or b)

I am not sure where to start with the simplification.
If anyone could tell me which law I should start with I would be very grateful.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: @AlexisVillar - language is irrelevant. It applies to any language that has an `if` or equivalent.

Comment: maybe that's right, but for specifically asking, how can we provide a solution if on this question if I give a VBA solution to python language? and also, considering the person who asks if he is a beginner in programming sir? sorry for bad English. @RickSmith

Comment: @AlexisVillar - The only thing certain is that the OP is new to SO. However, I posted an answer that should demonstrate why the language is irrelevant.

Comment: @RickSmith, does this answer the question of the person who asks sir?

Comment: @Anteman, before you ask a question sir you should probably research about it first. Please see this site to support, hope it helps. https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/d3nt/91/refman/index.htm#pickbasic-flashbasic/logical_expressions.htm

Comment: @AlexisVillar - The task was *to prove ... a tautology or a contradiction* and *tell me which law I should start with*. I have left the more formal proof for the OP, but I have provided the needed information. I believe I have answered the question.

Comment: @RickSmith Ok sir :) someday it will probably help me too :) thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183686/discussion-between-rick-smith-and-alexis-villar).

Answer (score 1):

> I would like some help with simplifying the following expression:
>
> (a and not b) or (not a or b)

Applying the [Substitution form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Substitution_form) of De Morgan's Law to the first part, `(a and not b)` becomes
`(not (not a or b))` giving `(not (not a or b)) or (not a or b)`.

Or, doing the same to the second part, `(not a or b)` becomes `(not (a and not b))`
giving `(a and not b) or (not (a and not b))`.

This results in a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)#Definition_and_examples) in the form "not A or A" for the first and "A or not A" for the second, after the [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_(logic)#Tautologies) of A for the common expressions of each of the above.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that since in our course litterature the De Morgan's Law is defined: not(a or b) -> (not a and not b).
There is no example of it being used in the way you described.

So I can, basically, use De Morgan's Law to also swap the contents of the expressions?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! But I do think it is a tautology! After the use of De Morgan's Law you can utilize the Inverse law -> not a or a = T. 
Since a is = (not a or b)! :)
Thanks for the help, clarified a lot!